# i have a many2many table,But i need to give domain as only the partner's record in the model needs to be shown in the many2many table

Tags: odoo

```
class HealthProfileInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'health.profile'

    health_profile_health_test_id = fields.Many2many('health.test',
                                          string ='Laboratory Test')
```

this the field connecting the 2 tables, how will give domain here? Do I wanna write a function or can give domain inside the field?

Comment: What the condition should be ?

Comment: condition is like only the partners data in the table needs to be shown

Comment: What does it mean, "only the partner's data in the table needs to be shown"?

Comment: records with his name as partner_id on the model named 'health.test'

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Do you need to show only records that have partner name as 'health.profile' name?

Comment: No sorry,I meant that there is a field named partner_id in both models 'health.profile and health.test(so the partner_id in model health profile can only access the records with the same partner_id in the model consultation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following domain:

```
domain="[('partner_id', '=', partner_id)]"
```

will filter records shown in the popup list after you click on the `add item` button link. only the test records with the profile partner will be visible.

> String domains are supposed to be dynamic and evaluated on the client-side only.

By default, users can create records from the popup list and they can select any partner in the `partner_id` field.

If you want to disable the creation option from the popup list use the `no_create` option:

```
options="{'no_create': True}"
```

If you want to keep the create button and force users to select the profile partner, you can create a new form for the `health.test` model and set the partner field invisible then pass the default partner value in context and force the many2many field to use that form.

```
<field name="health_profile_health_test_id" 
       domain="[('partner_id', '=', partner_id)]"
       context="{'form_view_ref': 'module_name.health_test_form', 'default_partner_id': partner_id}"/>
```

Remember that the form view with the lowest priority will be used as the default form view (The default priority value is `16`):

***Example:***

```
<record id="health_test_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">health.test Form</field>
    <field name="model">health.test</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="20"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <group>
                <field name="partner_id" invisible="True"/>
                ....
            </group>
            ....
        </form>
    </field>
    </record>
```

***Edit:***

String domains are dynamic and evaluated in client-side, for example the `"[('partner_id', '=', partner_id)]"` string domain will be evaluated to `[('partner_id', '=', 26)]`  and if the list has already selected records, the records will be excluded using `['!', ['id', 'in', list_of_ids]]`.

But when passing the domain as a list with the many2one field reference, the value will be of type `Many2one` and the server should raise a `RecursionError` when trying to get field attributes (tested in v12, v13).

If you look in the Odoo source code you will find many examples using a list domain but with simple values like booleans, strings, etc.

Comment: Thank you,its working.
But if you dont mind can you please tell me the difference of domain="[('partner_id', '=', partner_id)]" and domain=[('partner_id','=',partner_id)]). (why the double quotes does the trick?)

Comment: Thank you for your time and lesson,I heartly appreciate.